# Multiple Dependent Combo Boxes Cause Error When Scrolling

Tags: c#, combobox

I've created a test project that recreates the error I am experiencing in a program that I was told to fix. You can view it at http://tomsfreelance.com/stackoverflow/comboBox/ (Code is at bottom)

The following error occurs when I click on the `picturebox` button for the second combo box and scroll up using the middle mouse wheel. The key point here is that the first combo box must be selected - which happens when you first launch the application.

The error occurs in this snippet:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex <= 0)
        {
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
            comboBox3.Items.Clear();
            comboBox3.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Here is what the application does:

- When the first combo box is set to it's first item, the second combo box is set to it's first item, it's items are cleared, then it is disabled.
- This is true for the second combo box in relation to the third combo box.

Now, each combo box listens to the event `SelectedIndexChanged`. So when the first combo box is changed to it's first item, the second combo box is set to it's first item.

If you run this in the debugger, you'll have to enable error breakpoints otherwise the VS debugger will act as if nothing is wrong. If you run the independent exe, you will receive the error message.

**Why is this error message happening?** I can fix the error message by removing the selected index and moving enabled above the `Items.Clear`. I'm more curious as to why it is happening, though. It also seems to me that having two active elements at the same time might be a windows bug? (On top of this bad programming sample.)

[image]

This question is a follow-up question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150063/combo-box-scrolling-up-with-mouse-wheel-causes-error#comment26589550_18150063

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBoxTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int refillPrefix = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initComboBox();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 4;
            comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 5;
        }

        public void initComboBox()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; ++x)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Test " + x.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void fillCombo2()
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; ++x)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add("Test " + refillPrefix.ToString() + "_" + x.ToString());
            }
            refillPrefix++;
        }

        public void fillCombo3()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; ++x)
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add("Test " + refillPrefix.ToString() + "_" + x.ToString());
            }
            refillPrefix++;
        }

        private void comboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = !comboBox1.DroppedDown;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.DroppedDown = !comboBox1.DroppedDown;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox2.DroppedDown = !comboBox2.DroppedDown;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                comboBox2.Enabled = false;
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                fillCombo2();
                comboBox2.Enabled = true;
                pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex <= 0)
            {
                comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 0;
                comboBox3.Items.Clear();
                comboBox3.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                fillCombo3();
                comboBox3.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to set or use an index of selected items, when tehre are none selected?

Check for combobox.selecteditems.count . If that is 0, exit the routine. This happens in combo boxes / list boxes when the selected index is changed, or items deselected. YOu basically want to check on every call, if there are not selected items, don;t work with any. The call should happen twice, on the second call, there will be selected items, and you can use them.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx suggests that I should be able to get the selectedIndex at any time. Setting the selectedIndex to -1 has the same error message as well. The combobox is not a multi-select combo box and the selectedItems member doesn't exist. (selectedItem does)